# Different margins for second page and onwards

Tags: xetex, geometry

I am aware of similar questions, however I would like the same functionality with

`\newgeometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=35mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm}`

or afterpage package..

to happen when there is a new page... I do not know when and if there are multiple pages, as this is dependent on the amount of content.

basically

first page

`\geometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=35mm, top=51mm, bottom=30mm}`

second page (dynamic when it starts

`\newgeometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=35mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: done, would love for somebody to answer my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=35mm, right=35mm, top=51mm, bottom=30mm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlength\newtop
\setlength{\newtop}{21mm}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@outputpage{\global \@colht \textheight}{%
\global\textheight=\dimexpr\textheight+\newtop\relax%
\global\topmargin=\dimexpr\topmargin-\newtop\relax%
\global\@colht\textheight%
\global\newtop\z@}{}{\err}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

**Explanation**

```
\patchcmd[<prefix>]{<command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
```

[etoolbox documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)

> This command extracts the replacement text of a `<command>`, replaces
>   `<search>` with `<replace>`, and reassembles the `<command>`.

We use `\patchcmd` to redefine the internal command `\@outputpage`:

```
\global\textheight=\dimexpr\textheight+\newtop\relax%
```

the new text height is the old text height plus `\newtop=21mm`

```
\global\topmargin=\dimexpr\topmargin-\newtop\relax%
```

the new top margin is the old top margin minus `\newtop=21mm`

**Note** `\topmargin` is an internal command `topmargin=top(geometry)-1in-headheight-headsep`

```
\global\@colht\textheight%
```

`\@colht=\textheight` `\@colht` is internal command used by latex for as `\textheight`

```
\global\newtop\z@
```

we set `\newtop=0(uniteoflength)` otherwise textheight and topmargin will be changed in every use of `\@outputpage` (i.e every page)

Comment: Dunno what this is, but it works! could you explain to me what each line actually does?

Comment: This is gold-dust – thank you @touhami. Can I ask for a hint how to adjust the 'other' margins with this method?